# How can I find the largest flat surface on Three.js geometry?

Tags: three.js

I import a glb file into Three.js, then I merge its geometries and compute the BVH for faster raycasting with [three-mesh-bvh](https://github.com/gkjohnson/three-mesh-bvh) so I have a Mesh looking like this:

[image: MeshBVHVisualizer]

I need to find the largest floor area on this mesh, which is likely to be this:

[image: floor area highlighted]

What I've currently did is to do a lot of raycasting to get the points with height near to zero, the yellow ones here:

[image: raycasts to the space]

So I got a binary matrix, which tells me the points that are near-zero height, then I search this matrix for the largest area of 1 values

I find this quite like a hack and I wonder if there's a better way to find this area